# Adobe applications - Case-sensitive volumes not supported Mojave

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, disk-utility, adobe

I am trying to install the adobe creative cloud apps. when the setup launched it shows this error :

> Case-sensitive drives not supported

I created a partition with the format APFS but nothing. Should I format the whole drive to change it?? if so how? Thanks.

[image]

[image]

Comment: When you created the APFS partition which formatting option did you choose? There are four APFS options available,

Comment: The one with APFS only.

Comment: I believe that the Adobe apps are going to write content to your system drive no matter what you do, so if your system drive is case sensitive you probably will not be able to install and use many of the Adobe products on that computer no matter what other drive you install them on.

Comment: So which format should I choose to format the mac tin order to support adobe apps?

Comment: @MohamedALOUANE you have created the boot drive with APFS(Case Sensitive)

Answer (score -1):

When you Erase a drive, or Add a volume to a Container, you will be given a choice of Format. By default, this is APFS, but it can be changed to "APFS Case Sensitive", which is presumable what you have already done.

You need to change the format to "APFS". Adobe applications have several 'issues' with case-sensitive volumes (even on HFS+) through errors of their own making.

Comment: But thats what I have in my newly created partition, see the first screenshot.

Comment: In which case, I would contact Adobe. That's what you're paying them a subscription for!